# Does maintaining more specific partial indices cost more to maintain than a consolidated general index?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id INT, 
  name TEXT,
  state TEXT,
  needs_advice TEXT
)
```

and there are 2 usage patterns

- querying users who need financial advice
- querying users who need relationship advice

and I'm thinking of adding these 2 partial indices or 1 generic index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_users_needs_financial_advice
  ON users(state, needs_advice)
  WHERE needs_advice = 'financial'
  AND state = 'help'

CREATE INDEX idx_users_needs_relationship_advice
  ON users(state, needs_advice)
  WHERE needs_advice = 'relationship'
  AND state = 'help'
```

and using a more generic index below

```
CREATE INDEX idx_users_needs_relationship_advice
  ON users(state, needs_advice)
```

What would the tradeoffs be between using these 2 partial indices versus the 1 more generic index? My initial impression is the 2 partial indices require less maintenance than the 1 generic index but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maintenance costs for rows that need to be indexed would be the same, but the more indexes you have the harder the optimizer has to think, so I'd expect that to be a loss.

On the other hand, it is nice to only have an index on the rows that you need, so that the index is smaller and fewer rows require index maintenance.

You can have the best of both worlds with this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON users (needs_advice)
WHERE needs_advice IN ('financial', 'relationship')
  AND state = 'help';
```

Adding `state` to the index is unnecessary, unless you want to have an index-only scan (and then you would probably have to add more columns).

Comment: Expanding the question a bit, would you know how auto vacuum interacts with more indices? Are there more dead rows to clean up for each index?

Comment: No, it would be the same. Except that recent versions can parallelize the index scans. Still, I would prefer a single index.

Comment: Would you know if having more indices results in additional IOPS usage? For example if I were to go with those 2 indices rather than your consolidated index

Comment: It should be roughly the same.

Comment: Following up on the `state` to the index being unnecessary. If this were a single partial index on `state = 'help' AND needs_advice = 'financial'`, would the index be 
`CREATE INDEX ON users () WHERE needs_advice = 'financial' AND state = 'help';`? Curious why `state` can be left off but not `needs_advice`

Comment: It can be left out. But there are two possible values, so there is an advantage in having it there.

Comment: What is the advantage when there are 2 possible values (`needs_advice`) compared to when there is 1 possible value (`state`)? Does including `need_advice` improve the efficiency of the index scan whereas adding `state` it would not?

Comment: Come on, that should be obvious: if there are two values, the index can be used to tell which value it is, so we don't have to fetch table rows to figure out which ones we need.

Comment: I see and I appreciate you for trekking through the followup questions. Your answers really helped solidify my understanding of indices!